# Using the Select() Method on a List

Tags: c#, listview, microsoft-metro

I'm using a `ListView` to display a collection of items, and I'm assigning those items like so:

```
page.Items = _sampleData.Cats.Select(obj => (object) obj);
```

This works great, each `Cat` is displayed in the list. Reproducibly, if I remove the `(object)` cast, and assign the Items using

```
page.Items = _sampleData.Cats.Select(obj => obj);
```

or

```
page.Items = _sampleData.Cats;
```

Then instead of the data being stored properly, the *children* of the *first* `Cat` are instead displayed in the list. This seems... not intuitive? Is there some edge case I'm hitting in my code that is performing differently if the `Items` are not explicitly `object`s, or does that cast really make a difference?

**Edit:** Additional code.

`Cats` is a List of `Cat` objects:

```
public class Cat : IEnumerable<Trait>, IEnumerable
{
    public String Name;
    // getter and setter

    public List<Trait> Traits;
    // getter and setter

    public IEnumerator<Trait> GetEnumerator() {
        return Traits.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The `ListView` is a Metro UI component:

```
<ListView x:Name="CatListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}" ...>
```

And the data is being provided to the `ListView` though a setter for `Items` in one of my classes:

```
private IEnumerable<object> _items;
public IEnumerable<object> Items
{
    get
    {
        return _items;
    }

    set
    {
        _items = value;
        CollectionViewSource.Source = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the `Cat` type look like? What is the type of `Cats`? What kind of `ListView` are you using (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, …)?

Comment: The `page.Items = _sampleData.Cats` should work, there must be an error. Could you post the code of _sampleData and Cats?

Comment: Ya what ListView are you using? Both WPF/WinForms ListView do not have a setter for .Items.

Comment: I would say the edge case if the item is an `IEnumerable` itself (rather than "not an `object`")

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the lack of initial code, was on my way out of the office. Question has been updated with additional information. @svick I'm using a XAML-defined Metro ListView, I assume this falls under the category of WPF? @Marc _sampleData is a pretty simple class with `Cats` as an ivar. Nothing special about the getter/setter, but I will post it also.

Comment: @liho1eye Cat is indeed an IEnumerable. Why would this make a difference, why would the `ListView` continue to traverse deeper into the model (finding the children) as opposed to using the elements it was provided?

Comment: @craig No idea, just throwing ideas out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to accomplish what you're doing is to use [Cast<>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
page.Items = _sampleData.Cats.Cast<object>();
```

---

(Original answer below, which is not so valid after all given the comments.)

This is because you **can not** assign a collection of a derived class to a collection of a base class.

Let's take LINQ out of the equation. `page.Items` is of type `List<object>`.  Suppose the following would compile (it doesn't):

```
page.Items = _sampleData.Cats;
```

Then, note it's perfectly valid to put anything that inherits from `object` into a `List<object>`.  **But**, in this case, our list of objects is really a list of `Cat`.

So, attempting the following would logically work out, because it appears that you're adding a `Banana` to a list of object, but the list is really a list of Cats.

```
var b = new Banana();
page.Items.Add(b);
```

You can't put a `Banana` in a `List<Cat>`.

Comment: But in fact, `page.Items = _sampleData.Cats;` *does* compile.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see `private IEnumerable<object> _items`. My assumption about the type of Items being a `List` was wrong.

Comment: No worries, it's always a bit of a mess compressing all these pieces into a single, human-who's-not-me-readable SO question. :)